# Fisher information $J_y(\theta)$ for transformation $y=F(x)$

Tags: estimation, estimators, fisher-information

Consider a multivariate random variable $x$ with density function $P_x(\theta)$ for a scalar parameter $\theta$. Assume the Fisher information $J_x(\theta)$ is known.

Now, for a transformation (deterministic mapping) $y=F(x)$ can you express $J_y(\theta)$ in terms of $J_x(\theta)$ and $F$?

Comment: It is possible to prove that $I_X(\theta)-I_Y(\theta)$ is positive semidefinite in general.

Comment: And, if $Y$ is sufficient, then $I_X(\theta)=I_Y(\theta)$.

Comment: Regarding your original question, think about this: if I tell you the value of $\xi=\mathrm{E}[g(X)]$, can you really find, in general, an expression for $\mathrm{E}[g(h(X))]$ in terms of $\xi$ and $h$ only?